# Feedback, question about my module and if i should change anything?

Tags: perl, perl-module, feedback

```
package My::Module;

# $Id$

use strict;
use Carp;
use Data::Dumper;
use DBI;

$My::Module::VERSION  = '0.1';

sub new {
    my ($class, %opt) = @_;
    my $opt_count = keys %opt;

    $class->set_error('');
    #return $class->set_error("Too many arguments to initialize.") if ($opt_count > 5);
    #return $class->set_error("Missing arguments to initialize.") if ($opt_count < 2);

    my $self = bless {
                      _DRIVER_OPTIONS  => $opt{'mysql'},
                     },$class;

    if (not defined $self) {
        return $class->set_error( "new() failed: " . $class->errstr );
    }

    if ($self->{_DRIVER_OPTIONS}->{Host} ne '') {
        $self->{_DRIVER_OPTIONS}->{DataSource} = 'DBI:mysql:database=' . $self->{_DRIVER_OPTIONS}->{Database} . ';host=' . $self->{_DRIVER_OPTIONS}->{Host};
    } else {
        $self->{_DRIVER_OPTIONS}->{DataSource} = 'DBI:mysql:database=' . $self->{_DRIVER_OPTIONS}->{Database} . ';';
    }
    $self->{Handle} = DBI->connect($self->{_DRIVER_OPTIONS}->{DataSource},
                                   $self->{_DRIVER_OPTIONS}->{Username},
                                   $self->{_DRIVER_OPTIONS}->{Password},
                                   { RaiseError=>1, PrintError=>1, AutoCommit=>1 }
                                  );
    return $self->set_error("new(): couldn't connect to database: " . DBI->errstr) unless ($self->{Handle});
    $self->{_disconnect} = 1;

    print Dumper \$self;

    return $self;
}

sub database {
    my $self = shift;
    if (@_) { $self->{Handle} = shift }
    return $self->{Handle};
}

sub set_error {
    my $class   = shift;
    my $message = shift;
    $class = ref($class) || $class;
    no strict 'refs';
    ${ "$class\::errstr" } = sprintf($message || "", @_);
    return;
}

*error = \&errstr;
sub errstr {
    my $class = shift;
    $class = ref( $class ) || $class;

    no strict 'refs';
    return ${ "$class\::errstr" } || '';
}

sub DESTROY {
    my $self = shift;

    unless (defined $self->{Handle} && $self->{Handle}->ping) {
        $self->set_error(__PACKAGE__ . '::DESTROY(). Database handle has gone away');
        return;
    }

    unless ($self->{Handle}->{AutoCommit}) {
        $self->{Handle}->commit;
    }

    if ($self->{_disconnect}) {
        $self->{Handle}->disconnect;
    }
}

1;
```

1. Is that the right way so i can
   re-use the database on my code
   instead of having to open a new
   connection or that will aswell open
   a new connection every time i use it
   ?
2. Should i change anything on the
   module ? or anything i did wrong ?

Currently i am just learning and thinked of doing my own engine module so i began with this.

Simple test code (the bellow code is not to be reviewed just a sample on how to use the module):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use lib 'path to module';
use My::Module;

my $session = My::Module->new(mysql     => {
                                            Database =>'module',
                                            Host     =>'10.0.0.2',
                                            Username =>'module',
                                            Password =>'module'
                                           }) or die My::Module->errstr;

my $dbh = $session->database();
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(q{
             SELECT session_id
             FROM sessions
          });
   $sth->execute() || die print($dbh->errstr);
my $ref = $sth->fetchall_arrayref({});
$sth->finish;

print Dumper \$ref;
```

Comment: I believe this would be more appropriate as a community wiki.

Comment: no problem will mark as it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than using a CPAN module to accomplish this task, here are my practical recommendations:

1. Don't return an error value from the constructor. Instead, throw an exception.
2. Access the internals of your class using accessors rather than using direct hash access.
3. If the user of your class did not enable `AutoCommit`, she chose not to enable `AutoCommit` for a reason. Therefore don't do:

   ```
   unless ($self->{Handle}->{AutoCommit}) {
       $self->{Handle}->commit;
   }
   ```

   in `DESTROY`.
4. Note that [bless](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/bless.html) is not going to fail so long as it is given a modifiable reference (compare this to, say, the behavior of `open` which can fail to open a file even though the argument to `open` is a valid filename and would indicate this situation by returning a false value). Therefore, checking the return value of `bless` does not serve any useful purpose. If you want to handle the possibility of `bless` failing, you will have to catch fatal runtime exceptions.

Comment: on #4, `bless` failure can not be caught as the OP wrote it, but `perl -e 'bless \1'` will certainly fail.  usually you will only run into something like this if you are doing a lot of reblessing and have a bug somewhere though

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using an existing database interface rather than rolling your own, as there are many secret gotchas that others have spent years figuring out and solving for you.  [DBIx::Connector](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBIx%3a%3aConnector) is excellent, and with its `fixup` mode, will let you reuse database connections, even across process forks.

Additionally, if you use [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose) you will never have to write your own object constructors or object fields again. :)

[DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBIx%3a%3aClass) combined with Moose would be even better, but not necessary until you find yourself needing more ORM-ish features.

Comment: that is not the point of this module and i am not looking for a module or framework that can connect to a databsae. it was just what i choose to do so i could learn a bit more about how to create, use and re-use modules within modules and the module itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your way of exposing errors is very, *very* oldfashioned. If something exceptional happens, why not raise a proper exception? You seem to have modelled your error handling after the `DBI` module. Note that `DBI` also has a `RaiseError` option. Using that is almost always more reasonable than using the oldfashioned `errorstr` version. Unfortunately DBI can't change it's default anymore now, but for new code I entirely don't see the reason to copy this flawed idea.

You're also constructing a DBI connection within your code, based on parameters the user provided from the outside. Do you have a good reason for doing that? Allowing the user to pass in the `DBI::dh` he constructed himself would be more flexible. Yes, that requires slightly more code on the outside to set up objects and wire them together, but it will also result in a cleaner design. If wiring up your objects manually bothers you too much, you might want to have a look at [`Bread::Board`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Bread%3a%3aBoard) to do the wiring for you instead of compromising on the design of your module.

Also, I second Ether's suggestion of using `DBIx::Connector`. It really takes a lot of pain out of managing database handles, which can be very error-prone.

Comment: +1 @rafl the error code is not mine i just borrowed from CGI::Session to debug the module for now as i am learning how to do stuff myself, so i am doing bit by bit. Actually the constructors is as is because i just started this today and the main goal i wanted was to initiate a connection and instead of creating a new connection within my code, to be able to re-use that same connection so i didnt paid much attention on how i wanted it to be but i am still playing with it so i will totally re-work it, aswell as working out the expections as you recommended.

Comment: will take a look at Bread::Board aswell thanks for the touchs.